# Redirection Based off user

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, redirect

I am trying to set up my customer site so that when customers go to the main page they are redirected to their libraries so as they cannot see the rest of the site. I have created a script editor web part and added the following code to the site:

```
if (!SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser["Customer Name"])
{
  SPUtility.Redirect("https://cheerpack.sharepoint.com/sites/customer-sites/customername/Forms/AllItems.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
}
```

What happens is that the person logs in and they are not redirected to the customer's library. It shows the regular default.aspx page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Tried SPRedirectFlags.Trusted?

Comment: @GennadyG I have not I'm trying to stick with a web part that runs javascript since I'm working with Sharepoint hosted on Office365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Server Side Object Model code in Script Editor web part. However, you can write JavaScript Client Object Model Code inside it. I am not sure what is the condition to check different customers in your case, however, the redirect can be easily achieved using JavaScript `window.location = "http://addressOfDcoLibrary"`. Paste this code in script editor webpart to check redirection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://addressOfDcoLibrary;
</script>
```

JSOM also provide OOB function for redirection `SP.Utilities.HttpUtility.navigateTo(url)` but under the hood it also uses `window.location`

Comment: Ok that makes sense could you point me in the correct direction to get the client to reference the redirect?

Comment: Yousef This actually helped a great deal. I figured it out by getting the user ID and then creating and IF statement to redirect them: `if (_spPageContextInfo.userId == 49)
{
window.location = "https://cheerpack.sharepoint.com/sites/customer-sites/Ameriqual/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
}`